# Google Chrome losing cookies after Ubuntu reboot

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, cookies

From few days I am experiencing weird issue. When I reboot system or even relogin, then I am logged out on sites on which I was logged or clicked 'remember me'. Problem appears only in Google Chrome (Firefox and opera are working well), for example:

1. log in to stackoverflow
2. log out from system
3. log in to system
4. unlogged on stackoverflow!

I do not know when exactly problem appeared, remember I was executing `localStorage.clear();` in console, but I think it should not be connected with this.

I am using latest Ubuntu 16.04, latest Chrome 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit). I also tried reinstalling and using different versions like `google-chrome-beta`, `google-chrome-unstable` but without effects.

What can be the problem causing this?

Edit: I asked this question on StackOverflow, because I thought it may be related with `localStorage.clear()`

**Fianlly fixed in 53.0.2785.143: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/fc6f304827896fb27397fc2a27f9f5717eff319c**

Comment: I have the same issue, I think just this version is broken and we need to wait for an update.,,

Comment: @TheFullResolution please report it in `menu -> help -> report an issue`

Comment: There is a related bug report on Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=631171

Comment: Having the same issue, left a comment on the chromium bug thread.

Comment: I have the same issue on Chrome 54.0.2840.71

Answer (score 5):

Exactly same issue since last few days running `Chrome 53.0.2785.101` (64-bit) on `Centos 7`. Since I don't log out from `centos` I can open and close chrome ad It will keep reading cookies saved but when I logout, at the next login it can't read cookies at all. Uninstalling e completely removing personal chrome settings directory (`/home/myuser/.config/google-chrome/` )didn't solve.

I made another test: saved new cookies in a chrome session, closed the browser, moved away the file `/home/myuser/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies`, opened again the browser and, as expected, it couldn't find previously saved cookies. After restoring the file in its original path, chrome read the saved cookies again. After logoff-logon from `Centos`, no cookies again, but the file is still there and unchanged.

Comment: Same issue here...

Version 53.0.2785.101 unknown (64-bit)

Comment: Same here on 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)

Comment: The Chromium issue suggests this is fixed in 55. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=631171

Comment: This isn't an answer :/