# Chrome: "Account sign-in details are out of date. Sign in again"

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, google-account

in the latest days my Google chrome for Linux (version 53.0.2785.116 64 bit) doesn't remember my google accounts. Each time I turn off the PC (and not each time I close chrome, I really need to log off and login again) I get to log into all accounts again. The button with my name in the upper right corner has a exclamation mark and, if I go to settings, I see the message "Account sign-in details are out of date. Sign in again"

[image]

[image]

Now, I don't really know what's happening here. I'm using chrome at the office without any issue, and can't see anything wrong in my google accounts. Also, I tried removing --purge google-chrome and deleting the whole .config/google-chrome folder. Reinstalled chrome, logged in, rebooted the computer, same issue.

Right now I'm using firefox with no issues but... I mean, it's frustrating not being able to use the browser I'd like to.

Do you know what could be the reason of such strange behaviour, and how to work around it?

Thank you
Marco

P.S. It seems like it may be an issue due to a very very low expiration token time (now it's the 29th of september, 21:45. It's going to expire in 25 minutes!)

[image]

Once I reboot

[image]

Comment: What Linux distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425499/google-chrome-losing-cookies-after-ubuntu-reboot

Comment: Ok, maybe it's related but that thread didn't solve the issue. It was closed due to being off-topic (is it?)

Comment: The main takeaway of that post is that there is already a patch to fix the problem and so the best thing to do is probably to wait for the patch to reach you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried installing chrome-beta. Nothing.
I solved it by installing chromium instead of chrome. Seems to work like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue was related to auto-login feature in Ubuntu (tried on both 16.04 and 16.10). Once I disabled auto-login everything started to work like a charm.

Alternatively, if you are more determined you can investigate other solutions: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/kypcRMrZpec/i1zVrSo-AAAJ

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue running Chrome 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit) on Windows 7. I can open and close chrome ad It will keep reading cookies saved but when I logout, at the next login it can't read cookies at all. Uninstalling e completely removing personal chrome settings directory

```
/home/myuser/.config/google-chrome/
```

It didn't resolved the issue.

I have saved new cookies in a chrome session, closed the browser, moved away the file

```
/home/myuser/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies
```

opened again the browser and, as expected, it couldn't find previously saved cookies. After restoring the file in its original path, chrome read the saved cookies again.

May be they stopped development of Chrome and moving all development to Chromium